# How to write Display String formula for each cell in CrossTab?

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, crosstab

Formula scenario: Retrieved data has a status column which its values is (-1, 0, 1, 2, 3),
I'd like to use formula to display string based on these values. I use Display String, but it doesn't work.

How could I write a formula to work for each cell in crosstab?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Formulas are pretty easy to write. Just create a simple if/if else/else than statement:

```
if {TABLE.COLUMN} = 1 then 'One' else 'Unknown'
```

And use that within the cross tab.

Answer (score 1):

use `GridRowColumnValue("column name")` to get the corresponding row or column value to want to evaluate for the cell in question

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but I hope this help someone else.

```
Select CurrentFieldValue
    Case 1:
        "A"
    Case 2:
        "B"
```

etc.